Python Notebook Export to PDF using VSCode with BasicTex
I am unable to export my Python Notebook to PDF using "Jupyter: Export to PDF" in VSCode. I have Pandoc and BasicTex installed via brew and I am able to export HTML and markdown documents from terminal, just not inside VSCode. I get the typical error that I do not have xelatex (TeX) installed. I have nbconvert installed via pip too :\
